# New project in android studio sets line endings (line separators) to LF even if settings say CRLF

Tags: android, android-studio, line-endings

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html) to set the default line separators of new projects to be CRLF. However, whenever I create a new project on android studio, they are always set to LF.

When I open the settings for the project, it even says `Line Separator: Windows (\r\n)` but all the files on the project are still in LF.

Every time I create a new project, I have to follow these [steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html#ac9eb053) to set all the line separators to CRLF.

I don't want to change the line separators every time I create a new project. How can I fix this?